# Subtotals daily monthly sales

Tags: google-sheets

I want a sales report what totalize my daily / monthly sales

What I do now is look at the date and when the date is changing I look in auxiliary cell (column D in my example)  what the total is at that moment and subtract that in the auxiliary cell, cell so i can use it for the next change of date.
This method works fine for me, but now I want a more complex spreadsheet with  several columns.
I look for a way to get subtotals without the auxiliary cells
 [image]

[example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xXJhCdN-POP7TQ6JYOGWuNMPTZCy3z3rPTxTbWZVyRQ/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple formula to be entered in every cell of the column:

```
=IF(B4 <> B5; SUMIF($B$4:B4; B4; $C$4:C4); "")
```

Or an arrayformula

```
=ArrayFormula(
  IF(B4:B100<>B5:B101; 
     SUMIF($B$4:$B$100; B4:B100; $C$4:$C$100); 
     ""))
```

This is using `;` instead of `,` to separate parameters as per the OP's locale.